# Answering machine with Amazon Connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

We are trying to receive customer calls through Amazon Connect and leave messages in Amazon Kinesis.

When we call Amazon Connect from our cell phones, the voice plays the expected message and the Beep tone sounds as expected. But then the call ends and we cannot leave a message. We tried removing Wait and Stop media streaming but the problem persisted. What are we doing wrong?

- Set Voice: OK
- Play prompt(Message): OK
- Play prompt(Beep): OK
- Start media streaming: NG

If you have a simple, easy to understand sample for this application, let me know!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is your Wait block. Wait isn't supported for voice calls, so immediately errors.

Replace the `Wait` block with a `Get Customer Input` block. Use `Text to speech` for the prompt, Set the prompt value manually to `<speak></speak>` and set `Interpret as` to `SSML`. Set it to detect DTMF and set the timeout to however long the message is allowed to be. From your flow above that is 10 seconds.

This should get the customers voice sent to the Kinesis stream and you can process the stream from there.

There is a really thorough implementation guide for voice mail [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/voicemail-for-amazon-connect/welcome.html). I've used this then altered it to suite my exact needs in the past.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. We forgot about this question, but we had already found the same answer as yours. The customer's audio is already recorded in Kinesis Video Streams. But we have not yet been able to convert this into a playable media file. Do you have any simple sample about it? I am thinking perhaps converting it to mp3 or something similar and saving it to S3.

Comment: Simple? No :(

If you follow the implementation guide I linked to, it installs a bunch of Lambdas, one of which does the processing of the Kinesis audio stream using the Connect CTR stream as well.

The source code for the Audio processor lambda is [here](https://github.com/amazon-connect/voicemail-for-amazon-connect/tree/master/source/aws-connect-vm-serverless/src/main) 

I have just installed the VM implementation as per the guide and then altered things to work as I need them to. That seemed simpler than tryingto get the audio processing part working on its own.

Comment: Umm...We already referred to it but we could not figure it out. Why does AWS offer such a difficult way? Perhaps all users just want to play media.

Comment: Yeah, it isn't pleasant. But its a hack of AWS services to do this. Connect is meant to be for  contact centres and most contact centres don't use or offer voicemail :) Maybe in the future they'll add it as a standard feature.